# Symfony 4 + Knpu Oauth 2 + Google - Log out redirect after log back in

Tags: symfony, google-cloud-platform

Symfony 4 app with the KNPU Oauth2 bundle.

To allow the user to log out, have added a link pointed at:

```
https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout
```

When the user clicks this they are logged out of my app and Google in general. The Google log in screen is displayed.

After logging back in the user is then sent to the Gsuite my account page at https://myaccount.google.com

I would instead like the user to be directed back to my app `app.example.com`.

What can I append to the link url to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect the user to `https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout`, you are logging the user out of his Google Account. If the user has Gmail running in another tab, he will be logged out of Gmail also. Most users do not want this to happen. Instead drop the session (cookies) that you have with the user. You can also revoke the Access Token.

[Google OAuth 2.0: Revoking a token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke)

If you want to actually log the user out of Google Accounts, use this code in your project. I use JQuery to attach this function to a button.

```
function logout() {
    document.location.href = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://www.example.com/mypage.html"
}
```

Note: You will also see references to logout of Google this way:

```
function logout() {
    document.location.href = "https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=https://www.example.com/mypage.html"
}
```

Comment: I used the first example <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=mysite.com">Logout</a> and got a 400 error.

Comment: PS Im happy to log out of Google everywhere, as this for GSuite users at our company that is purpose to provide domain wide logout in our intranet. I just want the user to be bounced back into our home page after logging back in to Google.